# Knockout bindings from JSON file issues

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I am using Typescript to define my Knockout ViewModel.

I have a JSON file, the structure of which can be seen [here](https://gist.github.com/k4kuz0/2a0a1f730f91f8c6589706cadcf93523) (Github gist as It's a bit large to paste here).

The structure is basically:

OrderLine (the root) -> milestones -> factory_date

Or orally: (many) order lines have (many) milestones, which each have (one) factory date.

I am trying to build a ViewMOdel with the following:

```
var FactoryAppViewModel = (function () {
function FactoryAppViewModel(seasonID) {
    var self = this;
    self.seasonID = seasonID;
    self.orderlines = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.buildViewModel();
}

FactoryAppViewModel.prototype.buildViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    var getOrderLines = HTTP.get("/season/" + self.seasonID + "/orderlines").done(function (data) {
        self.orderlines(JSON.parse(data));
    }).fail(function () {
        error("Could not get orderlines");
    });
};
```

As far as I know, the `JSON.parse` on the data here will apply the values to the orderlines `ko.observableArray([])`, However I need to apply a ko.observable to the order lines children (milestones), and to a milestones child (factory_date) as well. And I don't know how to do this. Least of all from JSON.

I have read [this](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html) but it didn't seem to help me.

I know that the observable isn't applied, because when i change a `factory_date` in the view, it doesn't update the viewmodel.

Any help would be appreciated. The javascript above is the compiled TypeScript.

EDIT:

Here is an example of the way I'm accessing the code in the view:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: orderlines">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: factory.name"></td>
            <!-- ko foreach: milestones -->
                <!-- ko if: factory_date == null -->
                    <td>
                        <span>TBA</span>
                    </td>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko if: factory_date !== null -->
                    <td>
                        <div class="wrapper-wrapper">
                            <div class="btn btn-primary dateChanger">
                                <span data-bind="text: moment(factory_date.milestone_date).format('DD-MM-YYYY')"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="date-update-wrapper text-center">
                                <input type="text" data-bind="attr: {value: moment(factory_date.milestone_date).format('DD-MM-YYYY')}" class="form-control datetimepicker">
                                <a class="save-date btn btn-success" data-bind="click: function(){$root.saveDate(factory_date, $parent)}"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></a>
                                <a class="cancel-date btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

The part that made me aware I had an issue was this part:

```
data-bind="click: function(){$root.saveDate(factory_date, $parent)}"
```

I made a simple saveDate method, which was `console.log(factory_date.milestone_date)`, and it returned the default JSON data, despite me editing it in the view (using the datepicker).

Comment: Can you post your relevant markup and data-binds as well?

Comment: I've edited with a bit more information about how I accessed the information in the view. I hope that's what you meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knockout does not map children in lists to observables by default. There is a plugin called [ko.mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) that can help you achieve what you are looking for.

You can set up a "children" mapping, or loop through your children, manually making them observable (In this case from JavaScript):

```js
var mappedChildren = [];
var children = someObj.children();
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
  var mappedChild = ko.mapping.fromJS(children[i], mappingFunction);
  mappedChildren.push(mappedChild);
}
someObj.children(mappedChildren);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What would the mappingFunction do, though?